# Is there a way I can compact this if-then statement involving string find() method?

Tags: python

I have this object I converted to a string. If the sting does not contain a string like "Ei" denoted with -1 param, then print/display the object.

```
if str(p2eq).find("Ei") == -1 and str(p2eq).find("gamma") == -1 and str(p2eq).find("Piecewise") == -1\
and str(p2eq).find("li") == -1 and str(p2eq).find("erf") == -1 and str(p2eq).find("atan") == -1\
and str(p2eq).find("Si") == -1 and str(p2eq).find("Ci") == -1 and str(p2eq).find("hyper") == -1\
and str(p2eq).find("fresnel") == -1 and str(p2eq).find("Li") == -1:  
    display(p2eq.lhs)
```

I feel like there is a more efficient way to write this logic. I tried the code below, but it gives me several outputs when I just want one output.

```
for i in ["Ei", "gamma", "Piecewise"]:
     if str(p2eq).find(i) == -1:
          display(p2eq.lhs)
```

Comment: YOU want ALL of those things to be not found, right?  `if all(p2eq.find(s) == -1 for s in ('Ei","gamma","li","erf","Si","Ci", etc...)):`.

Comment: Thank you, Tim Roberts. This works perfectly. 

`if all(str(p2eq).find(s) == -1 for s in ("Ei","gamma","li","erf","Si","Ci", "hyper","fresnel","Li")):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a set (or list) of all the keywords you're looking for, then use `any()` with a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) to check if any of them are present.

You can also use `needle not in haystack` in place of the clunkier `haystack.find(needle) == -1`.

```
keywords = {
    "Ei",
    "gamma",
    "Piecewise",
    "li",
    "erf",
    "atan",
    "Si",
    "Ci",
    "hyper",
    "fresnel",
    "Li",
}

if not any(kw in str(p2eq) for kw in keywords):
    display(p2eq.lhs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `for-else` construct instead to call `display` only if the loop does not `break` from any match:

```
s = str(p2eq)
for i in ["Ei", "gamma", "Piecewise"]:
     if i in s:
         break
else:
    display(p2eq.lhs)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution based on sets. This also won't trigger matches in `atanx` cases (it's not a whole `atan` word as you can notice).

```py
# define this somewhere once (globally)
keywords = {"Ei", "gamma", "Piecewise", "li", "erf", "atan", "Si", "Ci", "hyper", "fresnel", "Li"}

# split a string into words, build a set and intersect them
words = set(str(p2eq).split())
if not words.intersection(keywords):
    do_your_thing()
```